# Validate form with Bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to validate a form with jQuery but can not get it to work.
I have seen several examples and I do not work properly.

I have put several alerts and when I do click in the search button, it work, but does not enter in the error function to validate the required fields because not show me the alert

HTML

```
<div id="partial-customertype-personal">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-3">
        <label for="customernumberF" class="control-label">Customer Number (F)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer-numberF" name="customer-numberF" maxlength="9" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-md-5">
    <label for="surname" class="control-label">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" maxlength="50" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
    <label for="datebirth" class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date-birth" name="date-birth" maxlength="10" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>                      
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
    <label for="postcode" class="control-label">Post Code</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" size="4" id="post-code" name="post-code" maxlength="8" />
</div>
```

JS

```
submitForm : function($scope){
        alert('submit OK');
        // solo permites números
        $("#customer-numberF, #card-number, #account-number, #customer-numberJ").keypress(function(key) {
            if(key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) return false;
        });

        $("#search").on( "click", function() {
            alert('search OK');
            /*http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/*/  
            new FormValidator('myform', [{
                name: 'customer-number',
                display: 'Customer Number',
                rules: 'numeric'
            }, {
                name: 'surname',
                display: 'Surname',
                rules: 'alpha_numeric'
            }, {
                name: 'date-birth',
                display: 'Date of Birth',
                rules: 'required|max_length[10]'
            }, {            
                name: 'post-code',
                display: 'Post Code',
                rules: 'numeric|max_length[8]'          
            }], function(errors, evt) {
                alert('error DON'T WORK');

                var SELECTOR_ERRORS = $(".error_box"),
                    SELECTOR_SUCCESS = $(".success_box");

                if (errors.length > 0) {
                    SELECTOR_ERRORS.empty();

                    for (var i = 0, errorLength = errors.length; i < errorLength; i++) {
                        SELECTOR_ERRORS.append(errors[i].message + '<br />');
                    }

                    SELECTOR_SUCCESS.css({ display: 'none' });
                    SELECTOR_ERRORS.fadeIn(200);
                } else {
                    SELECTOR_ERRORS.css({ display: 'none' });
                    SELECTOR_SUCCESS.fadeIn(200);
                    //ok form validado, muestro tabla
                }

                if (evt && evt.preventDefault) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                } else if (event) {
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }
            });
        });         

        $("#clear").on( "click", function() {
            CustomerSearch.resetForm($scope);
        });             
    }
```

I change this code `$("#search").on( "click", function() {` for This other `$("#search").click( function() {` and it doesn't work too.

Now I'm beginning to use some AngularJS, for this I put in JQuery "$scope", I take it off if it is what is failing me, but I still does not work

Comment: You have a serious syntax error here:  `alert('error DON'T WORK')`... notice how there is a single quote within two single quotes.  The SO visual formatting of the code in your OP reveals this immediately.  Also, please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when your question has nothing to do with this plugin.

Comment: To fix the alert issue, escape the `'` with a ``\`` like so: `alert('error DON\'T WORK');`

Comment: I put this alert in english now, but in my code is in spanish like alert('entra en funcion error'); this is my alert exactly in my code, sorry by my mistake in this code, only I put this because I wanted to say the function error did not work

Comment: here's something that might work for you https://github.com/MarkHill89/validator